Is series $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2n}{\sqrt{n}} $ convergent or divergent?
If I look logically and compare the graphics of the two functions
$$\begin{align}
y_1 &= \sqrt{x} \\
y_2 &= \ln^2{x},
\end{align}$$
I suggest that the second function increases faster rather than the first, and I logically understand that the series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2n}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{equation}
will be divergent. So the limit by L'Hôpital's rule is $0$.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {{\ln^2{n}}\over{\sqrt{n}}} = {{\infty}\over{\infty}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {{2\ln{n} \cdot {{1}\over{n}}}\over{{1}\over{2\sqrt{n}}}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {{4\ln{n}}\over{\sqrt{n}}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {{4 \cdot {1}\over{n}}\over{{1}\over{2\sqrt{n}}}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{{8}\over{\sqrt{n}}}=0.
\end{equation}
So my question: why does the limit by L'Hôpital's rule tend to $0$ and not to $\infty$? And what will be the series?

square root actually grows faster than the logarithm squared. Your limit computation is correct. As for the series, that's a different question, try to think about it more

Hint: $\frac{\ln^2n}{\sqrt n}\ge\frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ large enough.

@Gary How you compute this two ?

@BatyrbekAllamzharov Well, can you see that $\ln ^2 n \ge \frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}$ for $n\ge 3$?

In this case a simple comparison is enough. For $n \ge 3$, we have $\frac{\ln^2 n}{\sqrt{n}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. hence, the divergence of $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ implies the divergence of our series.

If the limit to infinity of the function that you are taking the sum over is non-zero, then the function diverges. However, the converse is not true: if the sum diverges, the limit to infinity of the function can really be anything. Your problem is a good example of this. Another well-known example is the harmonic series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \to\infty,$$
even though $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$. So, if the limit goes to 0, the test is inconclusive and you need to do more work.
